# Thunderbird not willing to start firefox when binary replaced with symlink

Tags: symlink, firefox, thunderbird, alternatives

I've been using the Debian "alternatives" mechanism to support multiple installed versions of Firefox. Regardless of the specifics, the bottom line is that instead of `/usr/bin/firefox` being a binary, it is now:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Aug 12 16:56 /usr/bin/firefox -> /etc/alternatives/firefox
```

and

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Aug 13 17:07 /etc/alternatives/firefox -> /usr/bin/firefox.dpkg
```

This seems just fine and I can start Firefox from the command-line, or using an Alt+F2 launcher in my desktop environment etc. However, Thunderbird doesn't like it. When I now click web links in Thunderbird, I get a dialog box which says

> **Close Firefox**
>
> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing firefox process, or restart your system.

Surely that's not the case, right? What do I do?